# Track who paid on behalf membership fees

Tags: civimember

Is there a way to track easily who paid for the membership incase of on-behalf membership payment?

Can extract data from Activity record (using [submitteddonotionreport extension](https://github.com/pradpnayak/org.civicrm.submitteddonotionreport)) but its not accurate always